# Where is masstransit retry method?

Tags: c#, masstransit

Where is it?

```
var sessionFactory = CreateSessionFactory();

var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Host("rabbitmq://localhost/");

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("submit-order", e =>
    {
        e.UseMessageRetry(r => 
             r.Immediate(5)); //<--- THIS METHOD DOES NOT EXIST

        e.Consumer(() => new SubmitOrderConsumer(sessionFactory));
    });
});
```

For example we have this doc: REMOVED

Or we have this doc:
https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#retry

And none of them work.

**PS**

Actually, Im really frustrated about whole documentation - it is either old or written by "someone" who seen masstransit somewhere in universe. Where I can read actual documentation or is it better to switch to other bus frameworks?

Comment: The vid is from beginning this year... are you sure you don't just miss an extension library? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pKxf6Ii-3ow

Comment: I see him using extension, but have no clue WHERE this extensions is among around 30 extensions in nuget starting with MassTransit.

Comment: It appears that it's a part of the core `MassTransit` library. My project references `MassTransit.AspNetCore`, `MassTransit.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, and `MassTransit.RabbitMQ`, and the `Immediate` method is available in my startup.cs. You can see the method on their github here https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/blob/develop/src/MassTransit/Configuration/MessageRetryConfigurationExtensions.cs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely need to add `using GreenPipes` to your using statements. Most modern IDE's can auto-resolve using declarations based on assemblies. The only NuGet package required is MassTransit, as it depends upon all the required packages.

And this is the [official documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/exceptions.html#retry) – no idea where that other link is from but I've petitioned to have it disabled and they refused.

And it's unfortunate that you're raging on SO about the docs. I'm the author, and you're welcome to provide constructive feedback as to how they might be improved.

Comment: Thank you! Now I have those methods. It is probably good idea to include all of those using directives in examples. One of problems I encountered - endpoints. This is totally obscure as to what I need to put inside Uri to make it work (all those 'loopback'/'rabbitmq' and I don't know what else) - it needs it's own wiki table to describe Uri format for each particular transport.

Comment: Chris, it seems to be mine. It is there since the time I was converting the docs to GitBook. Will remove it, didn't know it is still public.

Comment: You don't have to know all that stuff, and they are documented: https://masstransit-project.com/usage/producers.html#send